# POSTGRES - Multiple operations in single transaction using psycopg

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a query which Id like to run in postgres.

It deletes, and then inserts (kind of implements an ugly way of upserting which is unfortunately needed in my scenario).

```
cursor, connection = get_pgsql_connection(...)

query = '''
     delete from table where name = 'xyz';
     insert into table (name, value, place) values
     ('A', 1, 0),
     ('B', 4, 1),
     ('C', 6, 2);
'''
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The question is: if anything for any reason fails in this query, then the entire operation (i.e. `delete` + `insert`) is aborted? For instance, if `delete` fails, will the inserts be aborted? Or similarly when one of the `insert` fails, will the `delete` be also rolled back?

Thank you.

Comment: ...just noticed the postgresql-9.1 tag. That's suuuuper out of date and unsupported. It doesn't change the answer, but there have been no bug fixes - including for security issues! - for 9.1 [since 2016](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire transaction will be rolled back. You can add a `select 1/0;` statement between the delete and the insert, or after the insert, and then check via a separate connection (with psql is fine) that the data didn't change to confirm this.

(psycopg2 does have an autocommit option that performs a commit after every statement, but it's off by default and I've never seen it used IRL.)

Comment: Thanks Adam. It helps. I ran some tests with broken sql, constraint violations and mismatched types in the insert statements and I can confirm that it rolls back safely.